# Showing grouped values in different table

Tags: laravel

This my table on Blade:
[table on Blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Krs3v.png)

This is the $orders data came from
[$orders variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZinE.png)

This my code on Blade:
[invoice.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJZGL.png)

I want to show on table like this. On the first table I want to show 'Cabe Merah' values, on the second table I want to show 'Cabe Hijau' value, and also in the following table.
[This is what I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZFfu.png)

Comment: hai mas, I suggest you edit your question by adding code instead of using ss (screenshot)

Comment: you can use where in colletion result , see your blade the 2nd foreach loop do like this 
  `@foreach ($orders->where('jenisCabe.name', $cabe->name') as $items)`. ... and why is $order the collection key ?